# What should come first: dispose() or setScreen()?

Tags: java, libgdx

What should come first: dispose() or setScreen() ?

```
myMethod(){
    myGame.setScreen(new Screen());
    dispose();
}
```

or

```
myMethod(){    
    dispose();    
    myGame.setScreen(new Screen());
}
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing what `dispose()` does and what `myGame.setScreen()` does.

Comment: @ThomasKläger, they tagged libgdx. These are common library functions in libgdx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases it shouldn't matter. `dispose()` happens instantly. `setScreen()` queues the screen that will be drawn in the next frame, so the effect of calling it is deferred until after `dispose()` is complete anyway.

I say "most" cases, because I suppose it's possible you're doing something weird in `dispose()` that relies on checking what the current screen is.